# Python sort list of lists partially reverse based on date

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have a problem.
I have list of lists that look something like this:

```
[
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]
]
```

I need sorting to be on date field(1st one), but each set of same dates must be sorted in reverse order.
Resulting list must look like this:

```
[
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
]
```

As you can see list is ordered by date but, for the same dates list is reversed.

dates are still descending
2019-3-29
2019-3-28
2019-3-22
but for each date, if there more than 1 element for that date, items are reversed.

for 2019-3-29 there are 2 element

```
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
```

and in resulting list of lists order is reversed

```
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
```

Unfortunately i can not find most pythonic way to do that, only ugly nested cycles

Comment: So when you want the decimal part in reverse order we dont sort on the actual values, but simply reverse the order? If that is the case might it be possible to first reverse the whole list. And then sort on datetime?

Comment: A tip, you could make the question easier to understand and answer if you would have simplified your datatypes. Datetime and decimal are not really important. So you could have said. I have a list that basically looks like this [integer, "strings"]. I want to sort first on the integer property, then if multiple integers are equal then I want these to show up in reverse order. Your current question is ok and readable enough. But it would be easier to read with more basic types like 1, 3, 5. What is important is how to sort in the way you described, not the actual datatypes.

Comment: Alexey could you please clarify if you need to sort the dates or if we can take it for granted that the data is already sorted on datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty to simplify the datatypes since it is easier to read this way.

```
# Simplified representation.
# a few random values at the start and then multiple 2's and that the current order is a,b,c
# We expect all values to be sorted on the integer part first. And that the order for the 2's is c,b,a at the end.
data = [
    [1, '-'],
    [5, '-'],
    [3, '-'],

    [2, 'a'],
    [2, 'b'],
    [2, 'c']
]


data = data[::-1]
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Printing the data will yield:

```
[1, '-']
[2, 'c']
[2, 'b']
[2, 'a']
[3, '-']
[5, '-']
```

Which I believe is that you wanted.

This solution is very easy to read which has its benefits when working with others.

`sorted` in python is a stable sorting algorithm. This is why you if you sort normally the order of 'a b c' is preserved. Thats why reversing first works, sorted will not change the order in which equal items appeared.

Note that this also works.

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)
data = data[::-1]
```

Here we do a reverse sort and then read the data backwards.

Comment: Very elegant! I feel it would be more pythonic to write as `sorted(reversed(data), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)` but regardless this is a great solution

Comment: very nice! I think you don't need the imports at all (see mtrw's comment) and you assume the data is sorted in the first place - as I read it, that's not clear from the question.

Comment: Thanks @mtrw and MrFuppes I will make an update. I was not sure what is the pythonic way to do that part. But it makes sense that the method that does not use imports is a good one!

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes the question is a bit unclear here. My understanding was that the second part should not be sorted, just reversed. But if the second part should be reverse sorted then one can change the data[::-1] reverse step to a reverse sort on the second part.

Comment: @MrFuppes I think the OP's "dates are *still* descending" (emphasis mine) means it's indeed already sorted by that.

Comment: @AlexTelon Under two other answers the OP commented that he indeed wants reversal, not sorting.

Comment: @HeapOverflow yes I can see some evidence for that interpretation. However OP also says "I need sorting to be on date field(1st one)" and also uses the term 'sort' in the heading. Your interpretation however is good since it date types very well can be sorted already. His comments on other answer do indeed speak of reversal. I however am still unsure if they apply only for the decimal part or for both parts.

Comment: @HeapOverflow But I can also see that "I need sorting to be on date field(1st one)" to mean "I want the current sorted order on date to be preserved". So there are two interpretations of this.

Answer (score 2):

An O(n) solution using `itertools.groupby` to group and reverse each date's items:

```
data = [d for _, g in groupby(data, lambda d: d[0]) for d in [*g][::-1]]
```

(This requires the dates to already be descending in the input, but your question, especially your *"dates are **still** descending"* sounds like that's indeed the case.)

Demo:

```
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from itertools import groupby

data = [
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]
]

data = [d for _, g in groupby(data, lambda d: d[0]) for d in [*g][::-1]]

for d in data:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by date, which reverses the dates but for each date keeps the order of the items (because it's a stable sort). And then reverse the whole thing, so your dates are descending again but each date's items are reversed.

```
data.sort(key=lambda d: d[0])
data.reverse()
```

Demo:

```
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

data = [
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]
]

data.sort(key=lambda d: d[0])
data.reverse()

for d in data:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')]
[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: dates = [
   ...: [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
   ...: [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
   ...: [datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
   ...: [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
   ...: [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
   ...: [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]
   ...: ]

In [5]: sorted(dates, key=lambda x: (x[0].day, x[1]), reverse=True)

Out[5]:
[[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite I wanted. As you can see in your answer `[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')]` but i need it to be `[datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')], [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')]`.  No need to sort values, only reverse the order.

Comment: @AlexeyIgnatyuk `[val for _, val in sorted(enumerate(dates), key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]))]`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Exactly, the op should use enumerate to sort based on the index. I didn't test the answer but it should work

Answer (score 0):

In Python, when you sort a list of iterables (like list, tuple, etc), element lists are sorted according to their values at first index. If they are same, then the values at the following index are compared.
The reversing of decimals are due to this.

The below is what you want:

```
... import datetime
... from decimal import Decimal
... from operator import itemgetter
... from itertools import groupby, chain
... 
... data = [
...     [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
...     [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
...     [datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
...     [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
...     [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
...     [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]
... ]
... date_sorted_data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
... 
... result = list(
...     chain.from_iterable(
...         [
...             reversed(list(g)) 
...             for k, g in groupby(
...                 date_sorted_data, key=itemgetter(0)
...             )
...         ]
...     )
... )
... 
... print(result)
... 
[[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')], [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')], [datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')], [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')], [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')], [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')]]
```

Comment: I don't need to sort 2nd index values, i need to reverse their order. For example it there were values 57,99,888,3 i need the result to be 3,888,99,57

Comment: @AlexeyIgnatyuk I add the code that does what you want. You can expand the one-liner as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that uses an intermediate data structure:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x,y in data:
    dd[x].insert(0,y) #key is date, value is reverse list of Decimals for each date
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {datetime.date(2019, 3, 29): [Decimal('45000.00'), Decimal('44819.75')], datetime.date(2019, 3, 28): [Decimal('0.00')], datetime.date(2019, 3, 22): [Decimal('-175.00'), Decimal('-350.00'), Decimal('-275.00')]})
>>> dataout = [[x,y] for x in sorted(dd.keys(),reverse=True) for y in dd[x]]
>>> dataout
[
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sort by date, and in case of tie sort by the reverse of the current position. Easy:

```
[value for _, value in sorted(enumerate(dates), key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]), reverse=True)]
```

Results:

```
>>> pprint([val for _, val in sorted(enumerate(seq), key=lambda x: (x[1][0], -x[0]), reverse=True)])
[[datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('44819.75')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 29), Decimal('45000.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 28), Decimal('0.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-275.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-350.00')],
 [datetime.date(2019, 3, 22), Decimal('-175.00')]]
```

Comment: Your shown results are the same as the *input*, not the desired output. And in your first snippet you forgot the additional `[0]`.